# 'It were far worse' - why 'were' instead of 'was'?

Tags: subjunctives, archaic-language

> "Thou must dwell no longer with this man," said Hester, slowly and
>   firmly. "Thy heart must be no longer under his evil eye!"
>
> "It **were** far worse than death!" replied the minister. "But how to
>   avoid it? What choice remains to me? Shall I lie down again on these
>   withered leaves, where I cast myself when thou didst tell me what he
>   was? Must I sink down there, and die at once?"
>  (Nathaniel
>   Hawthorne,The Scarlet Letter)

There is ‘were’ instead of ‘was’ after *it*. Is the sentence a kind of subjunctive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed subjunctive. Hawthorne is emulating the diction of the 17th century, when the subjunctive was still very much alive. For instance:

> If it were done when 'tis done, then 'twere well
>    It were done quickly.
>         —*Macbeth*, I,7

Today we would say

> If this were [over and] done [with] once it has been done, it would be good to do it quickly.

Similarly, we would translate Dimmesdale's reply as

> "It would be far worse than death!"